Hetzner pfSense cloud & dedicated proxmox VM - No internet
Hetzner has some strange routing needs for their servers, which gets even more complicated when you combine cloud and dedicated servers. I think I have the setup completed for like 99%, but am missing the final detail to get internet to the VM. Normal network is working.
The setup:

(cloud) private network range 192.168.0.0/16
(cloud & dedicated) Subnet 192.168.100.0/24 connected to vSwitch
(cloud & dedicated) Subnet gateway 192.168.100.1
(cloud) pfsense firewall 192.168.0.3 with openVPN server
(dedicated) proxmox server 192.168.100.101
(dedicated) Windows VM 192.168.100.110

** All parts can ping each other without a problem
** When connected to the VPN I can use remote desktop to access the windows VM.
** pfSense and proxmox can access the internet
** The windows VM can not access internet.
I've tried to set the gateway to either pfSense, the subnet gateway or proxmox without success. I also tried NIC Teaming and routing has been added:
Network Destination   Netmask      Gateway         Interface         Metric
192.168.0.0           255.255.0.0  192.168.100.1   192.168.100.110   26

pfSense has been set to Automatic outbound NAT rule generation. (IPsec passthrough included) and the rules have been set to allow any from any using any for LAN, WAN and VPN.
I'm running out of ideas on what to do to make this work.
